# Generate SQLs and prepared SQLs from DSL and DAO without `Database.connect` or having a `Transaction` with Kotlin Exposed

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I am trying to take advantage of Exposed's type-safe DSL on top of [Vert.x SQL Client](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-sql-client) to have both type-safety and throughput. I know currently Exposed doesn't support any reactive/async/non-blocking database clients yet (see #456, #732, etc.), but a simple workaround is to generate SQLs for them.

[Q: How to get a plain SQL query which will be executed?](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/FAQ#q-how-to-get-a-plain-sql-query-which-will-be-executed) provides a solution using `fun prepareSQL(builder: QueryBuilder): String` for `Query`s, and for `DeleteStatement`s, `InsertStatement`s, and `UpdateStatment`s, etc., I can use `fun prepareSQL(transaction: Transaction): String` and adapt the original library code a little bit to make it generate both plain SQLs and prepared SQLs. However, when I execute the code directly I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Please call Database.connect() before using this code
```

Since I don't use Exposed's API but use Vert.x SQL Client's to connect to the database, calling `Database.connect` and `transaction` would mean a waste of resources. So how do I do this without calling `Database.connect` or having a `Transaction`? I couldn't figure this out myself since it seems Exposed is too tightly coupled with JDBC and a lot of code's visibility is quite restricted. For example, I also tried creating a dummy no-op `Database` but couldn't succeed because it has a private constructor.

In addition, can I also generate SQLs using the [DAO API](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DAO)?